# C++ Pointers behaving weirdly

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, pointers

I have a 2D array of Pointers that point to instances of that Class Piece.
I declare the array like so:

Board.h :

```
private:
    typedef std::array<Piece**, Board::BOARD_SIZE> row_type;
    typedef std::array<row_type, Board::BOARD_SIZE> array_type;
    array_type* grid;
```

After that this code runs: (This is where the problem is)

```
grid = &array_type();
for (int i = 0; i < Board::BOARD_SIZE; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < Board::BOARD_SIZE; j++) {
        (*grid)[i][j] = NULL;
    }
}
(*grid)[3][3] = &Piece::white;
(*grid)[4][4] = &Piece::white;
(*grid)[3][4] = &Piece::black;
(*grid)[4][3] = &Piece::black;

ofstream fout;
fout.open("Debug.txt");
fout << "Board cpp" << &Piece::white << endl;
fout << "Board cpp 2" << (*grid)[3][3] << endl;
fout.close();
```

Piece::white & black variables are static inside the Piece class, and are initialized before this code runs.

The weird part is as you can see I run this statement:

```
(*grid)[3][3] = &Piece::white;
```

yet when I print out the address of each side I get different addresses! Why is this? I am new in C++ so please go easy on me!

Comment: So let me get this straight. You have a pointer to an array of arrays of pointers to pointers to `Piece`s. Does that not sound the slightest bit insane? Like I imagine an array of arrays of `Piece`s would do perfectly fine.

Comment: Ummmmm, yes. I do not quite understand why. I want to have a 2D array of pointers so that I can only use 2 actual instances of the class Piece. Obviously I am doing this wrong, please explain why! (I started C++ yesterday sorry)

Comment: If you're new to C++ you really shouldn't be (ab)using pointers like that.

Comment: #like #subscribe2014bestcomedianinstackoverflow Please instead of pulling cheap shots, help the poor old lady to cross the weird street called C++

Comment: Is this chess game? If yes, why you use dynamic objects `std::array`?

Comment: @user1724911, What do you mean by "dynamic objects `std::array`"?

Comment: This is for an Othello/Reversi game. A 2D array will do fine, but I want to use only 2 instances of class piece so it will be and array of pointers so that the elements point to either Black piece or White piece..

Comment: I'm completely serious. `array<array<Piece*>>` might help. (Or `vector` rather than `array `.) You might also want to look at `enum` for an alternative approach to a type with just two values (although your way does have some advantages).

Comment: @AlanStokes, The board size is fixed, so a vector really offers no benefit.

Comment: @chris The occasional lack of initialisation for the elements of an `array` always slightly worry me. Here either would work just fine.

Comment: so would this be good? 
**typedef array<array<Piece*, Board::BOARD_SIZE>, Board::BOARD_SIZE> PieceArray;**

Comment: @gopgop you could use an intermediary `typedef array<Piece*, Board::BOARD_SIZE> PieceRow;` and then  `typedef array<PieceRow, Board::BOARD_SIZE> PieceArray;` that's slightly more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question: how do you print "the addresses on each side"?

In principle, that line of code

```
(*grid)[3][3] = &Piece::white;
```

just copies the address of `Piece::white` into the variable identified by the address stored at grid[3][3]. The address itself (i.e. `grid[3][3]`) is not supposed to change, only the value to which it points.

Answer (score 1):

This line is not good:

```
grid = &array_type();
```

You are storing the address of a temporary object in `grid`. Anything that accesses `grid` is subject to undefined behavior.

I would suggest changing it to

```
grid = new array_type();
```